# Paired t-test on large sample that *should* be normal, but isn't (or Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test)?

Tags: r, t-test, nonparametric, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

A dataset contains the number of fast food restaurants per thousand people for each county in the USA, for two different years (five years apart).  3,143 rows.

None of the following are normally distributed: the 2009 data, the 2014 data, the difference between the two years, or the percentage difference between the two years.

Here is a ggqqplot (in R) of one of the years, and of the difference:

[image]

I removed around 30 outliers from the data (the graphs), which I restored for the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test.

I am finding conflicting information as to whether I can use the paired t-test to see if there is a significant change in the rates/1000 people between the two years.  One reference says if it's a very large set of data that should be normal, use the paired t-test even if it isn't.  Another says to use the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test.  Which is correct for this data?

In case you are curious, the average of the rates went up around 1.5%, and both the paired t-test and the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test show very high significance (> E10).

Another question is do I need to weight the samples somehow?  The populations of the counties are available. The test is asking about changes in the geographic areas (counties).  I think this is okay, as I've seen peer-reviewed studies of animal traits in different areas (paired t-tests over years), and they are treated the same in spite of the size of the area or it's population.

UPDATE

There is also data for the number of fast food restaurants.  The graphs are worse than the ones above, on the data, and on the differences.  Do I use a paired t-test, as the data "should" be normal?  I know paired t-tests can be used on data like this, such as changes in the numbers of crabs on a number of different beaches between two years.

Comment: I think one issue here that you did Not raise is that data within years might be considerably dependent, Biasing your SEs and therefore your test . Why do you want to test anyway if you have Data on all counties?

Comment: So all the published studies about animal population changes are invalid?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not read all studies about animal population changes, but if observations are dependent and this is not accounted for in the model, then yes: the standard errors are biased.

Comment: You are saying the dependency is the previous population?  What about people that show improvement, but not a cure, with a new medication?  The new health measure is tied to the old one.

Comment: No I meant dependency *within* years. The number of fast-food restaurants in county X is probably dependent on the number of fast-food restaurants in the neighbouring count Y. 
I think my second point is more important, however: Why do you want to test if you have data on all counties? 
What is your population to which you want to draw inference?

Comment: I'm just doing significance tests.  Null and alternative hypothesis.

Comment: Then how would you formulate your null and your alternative?

Comment: Null: The average number of fast food restaurants / 1,000 people, across the USA and assessed on a county level, did not significantly change between 2009 and 2014.  Alternative (one-tailed): The average number "..." increased.

Comment: Significance is not a part of the Null/ Alternative, it is a property of the obtained sample. 
E.g. I want to test that the average height of men in Germany is 1.80 m, I sample 100 people randomly and get a p-value of 0.01, then my **result** is significant, leading me to reject my null hypothesis. In this case German men is the population and I want to draw conclusions from my 100 person sample to Germany. What are the 100 men/ Germany in your case?

Comment: My point is that in analogy you observe all Men in Germany (in your case all counties), so the question whether the difference in the sample is large enough that it is due to a difference in population and not due to random sampling does not make sense, because your sample is the whole population.

Comment: Sometimes people then argue that the restaurants in year X are a sample from a hypothetical distribution of all the fast-food restaurants that could have been in year X but I am not sure whether this is what you want.

Comment: The significance test is whether the mean changed.  It's a paired t-test.  You are describing a one sample t-test against a known mean.

Comment: The underlying Príncipe is the Same.

Comment: Yes, I have the totals, and I'm not making inferences from a samples.  I just need to know if the differences are statistically significant.